# Radio button to disable select ( 'else' not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, radio-button

This is what i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('input:radio[name="RADIOSELECTOR"]').change(function() {

        if ($(this).val()=='one') {
                $('#ones').removeAttr('disabled');
             $('#twos').attr('disabled',true);
        } else if ($(this).val()=='two') {
            $('#ones').attr('disabled',true);
             $('#twos').removeAttr('disabled');
        }  else  {
          $('#ones').attr('disabled',true);
                  $('#twos').attr('disabled',true);
         }


                     });
</script>

<form name="order" action="managecart.html" onsubmit="return AddToCart(this); return ValidateCart(this);">
<input name="PRICE" type=hidden id="PRICE" value="" />
<input name=NAME type=hidden id="NAME" value="" />
<input name=ID_NUM type=hidden id="ID_NUM" value="" />
<input type=hidden name="SHIPPING" value="0.00" />
<input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="lose" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='59.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitiazer replacement'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGL'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer repair  <b>59.99$</b><br><br>
<b> Combo repairs:</b><BR><br>
<input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="lose" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='74.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + battery repair'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLB'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + battery repair = <b> 74.99$</b> 25$ in savings!<br>

<input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="one" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='79.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + combo '; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLC'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + <select id="ones" name="ADDITIONALINFO2" disabled="disabled">
<option value=" "></option><option value="Home button">Home button</option> <option value="Power button">Power button</option><option value="Mute switch">Mute switch</option><option value="volume button">Volume button</option></select>

 = <b>79.99$</b> 30$ in savings!<br>

<input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="two" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='99.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + combo + ''ADDITIONALINFO3'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLBC'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + battery +  <select name="ADDITIONALINFO3" id="twos" disabled="disabled"><option value=" "></option><option value="Home button">Home button</option> <option value="Power button">Power button</option><option value="Mute switch">Mute switch</option><option value="volume button">Volume button</option></select> = <b>99.99$</b> 30$ in savings!<br>

<input name="QUANTITY" type="hidden" value="1" /><br>
<input type="image" src="./images/addtocart.png" align="center" name="BUY" value=" Add to cart " ALT="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/uSmVD/86/

the script doesn't work in html file. How to fix this ?
 here is the actual page im trying to get this to work http://icuretech.com/revision/iphone-3g-glass-repair.html

Comment: Can you format your code with proper indentation to make it legible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uSmVD/79/ this is whats happening with else

Comment: Because the middle block should use `else if`, not `if`. Give [this](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/controlflow3.html) a read.

Comment: that did help "if, else if, else" way works great

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an input whose value is `lose1`. You have `lose` and `1` individually as values for certain inputs, but not both, so that expression will never evaluate to what you want it.

Comment: true, I did correct that but when i do else { $('#ones').attr('disabled',true);
                  $('#twos').attr('disabled',true);
         }
 i doesnt work properly , why is that? Also when i put the script in html body its not working, thank you for reply

Comment: Ok so for starters you're removing an attribute called "disable" that you don't have assigned in the first place. So if you hit that else statement before anything else, it can't remove an attribute that isn't there from the start. Also, I don't even see an else statement in the script snippet you provided here in the code. Finally, you need to make sure you wrap your Javascript in a <script > tag if you want to embed it in the body, but I would highly advise against that.

Comment: @Rafal: When you make changes/corrections to your code, you need to update your question please.

Comment: ok added disabled="disabled" to the select and with if,else if, else way it works great, I wrap the script in <script> but still doesnt work. also tried in js file and nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

   <script>
     $('input:radio[name="RADIOSELECTOR"]').change(function() {

        if ($(this).val()=='one') {
                $('#ones').removeAttr('disabled');
             $('#twos').attr('disabled',true);
        } if ($(this).val()=='two') {
            $('#ones').attr('disabled',true);
             $('#twos').removeAttr('disabled');
        }   if ($(this).val()=='lose')  {
          $('#ones').attr('disabled',true);
                  $('#twos').attr('disabled',true);
         }
           if ($(this).val()=='lose1')  {
          $('#ones').attr('disabled',true);
                  $('#twos').attr('disabled',true);
         }

   });

   </script>
<form name="order" action="managecart.html" onsubmit="return AddToCart(this); return ValidateCart(this);">
<input name="PRICE" type=hidden id="PRICE" value="" />
<input name=NAME type=hidden id="NAME" value="" />
<input name=ID_NUM type=hidden id="ID_NUM" value="" />
<input type=hidden name="SHIPPING" value="0.00" />
<input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="lose" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='59.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitiazer replacement'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGL'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer repair  <b>59.99$</b><br><br>
<b> Combo repairs:</b><BR><br>
<input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="lose" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='74.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + battery repair'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLB'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + battery repair = <b> 74.99$</b> 25$ in savings!<br>

<input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="one" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='79.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + combo '; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLC'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + <select id="ones" name="ADDITIONALINFO2">
<option value=" "></option><option value="Home button">Home button</option> <option value="Power button">Power button</option><option value="Mute switch">Mute switch</option><option value="volume button">Volume button</option></select>

 = <b>79.99$</b> 30$ in savings!<br>

<input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="two" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='99.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + combo + ''ADDITIONALINFO3'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLBC'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + battery +  <select name="ADDITIONALINFO3" id="twos" ><option value=" "></option><option value="Home button">Home button</option> <option value="Power button">Power button</option><option value="Mute switch">Mute switch</option><option value="volume button">Volume button</option></select> = <b>99.99$</b> 30$ in savings!<br>

<input name="QUANTITY" type="hidden" value="1" /><br>
<input type="image" src="./images/addtocart.png" align="center" name="BUY" value=" Add to cart " ALT="Add to Cart">
</form>
```